# Universal Image loader not working properly with android spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, universal-image-loader

I am using nostra13 universal image loader to load images from api of different social medias. 
Following is the code of my adapter class.

```
    imageLoader.displayImage(objects.get(position).getFeedImageUrl(),viewHolder.image, defaultOption, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
               viewHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason.getType()) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case DECODING_ERROR:
                        message = "Image can't be decoded";
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_DENIED:
                        message = "Downloads are denied";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                viewHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                viewHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that I show the spinner visible when the photo is loading and in      `onLoadingComplete` .I set the visibility gone but still the spinner is visible when photo loading completes. As i scroll my list and come back to the same position then only the spinner visibility goes away.

Initialization  of image loader in the constructor is as follows.

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> objects) {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.objects=objects;
    this.context=context;
    defaultOption = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.whitebackground)
                    .showStubImage(R.drawable.whitebackground)
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.whitebackground)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisc(true)
                    .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                                        .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
                                        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOption)
                                        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
                                        .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); 
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Beatles Light Light.ttf");
}
```